# std::transform on a multiset giving me error C3892

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

I am trying to understand how the std::transform function works, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the following code. I want to take a multiset ms, add 1 to the contents of each element and store them in a new multiset msc. Here is what I have:

```
int op_increase(int i) { return ++i; }

int main()
{

std::multiset<int> ms = {1,1,2,2,3};
std::multiset<int> msc;
std::transform(ms.begin(), ms.end(), msc.begin(), op_increase);

return 0;
}
```

However I get the following error:

C3892: _Dest: you cannot assign to a variable that is const

Comment: That's not a _runtime error_!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was not utilizing the correct argument to `std::transform` that allows insertion into an empty container.  This requires using an iterator that is intelligent enough to call the appropriate function that calls the container's `insert()` function.

The solution is to provide `std::transform` the `std::inserter` iterator that automatically inserts into the empty `multiset`.  Here is an example:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int op_increase(int i) { return ++i; }

int main()
{
    std::multiset<int> ms = {1,1,2,2,3};
    std::multiset<int> msc;
    std::transform(ms.begin(), ms.end(), std::inserter(msc, msc.begin()), op_increase);
    // msc now contains 2,2,3,3,4  
}
```

Note the `std::inserter` is used, and not merely `msc.begin()`.  The inserter will automatically insert the items into the map.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/VPvKsO)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `std::multiset<T>::begin()` returns a `std::_Tree_const_iterator` type. That's why you cannot change its value. This behavior is sensible: the `std::multiset`, like `std::set`, is a sorted container typicaly implemented as a red-black tree, and thus change of a value of one element may require update of the whole data structure. If user really wants to do this, he may erase a node and add it back.

To better understand the `std::transform` behavior, you may use `std::vector` container instead of `std::multiset`. [Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) contains a good example of code using `std::transform`.

Also, as far as I understand from your code, you try to add the resulting data into the initially empty `std::multiset`. To achieve this functionality, you may use `std::insert_iterator` ([Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/insert_iterator/)), like this:

```
int op_increase(int i) { return ++i; }

int main()
{
    std::multiset<int> ms = {1,1,2,2,3};
    std::multiset<int> msc;
    std::transform(ms.begin(), ms.end(), inserter(msc, msc.begin()), op_increase);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so what should I do if I want to use std::transform with a multiset?

Comment: Ya I saw the example posted on cplusplus.com and I'm able to understand it, but I need to do it this way specifically for an assignment.

Comment: @lebman -- Your assignment is wrong-headed.  You cannot use `std::transform` to insert items into an empty container without using an iterator that is smart enough to do the insertion.